# Why were Aragorn and Arwen buried in separate places?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Is there any evidence from Tolkien which gives reasons as to why the said characters are buried away from each other? From what I gather:

- Aragorn died on March 1, 120 of the Fourth Age and was buried in a Royal Tomb of Gondor alongside Merry and Pippin.
- Arwen died in Year 121 the Fourth Age (date unknown?) and was buried at Cerin Amroth (Lórien).

Was it not common in Middle-Earth for Kings and Queens to lie buried with one another or did Tolkien have a mantra of 'bros before...girls'?

Comment: Arwen wasn't really buried. She more or less went to Cerin Amroth, layed down, and never got up.

Comment: Cheers for that @S.Fruggiero, guess I was too hasty to ask a question here that I probably missed that =)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The Aragorn and Arwen material in Return of the King Appendix A tells that after the death of Aragorn:

> ...Arwen went forth from the House, and the light of her eyes was quenched, and it seemed to her people that she had become cold and grey as nightfall in winter that comes without a star. Then she said farewell to Eldarion, and to her daughters, and to all whom she had loved; and she went out from the city of Minas Tirith and passed away to the land of Lórien, and dwelt there alone under the fading trees until winter came. Galadriel had passed away and Celeborn also was gone, and the land was silent.
>
> There at last when the mallorn-leaves were falling, but spring had not yet come, she laid herself to rest upon Cerin Amroth; and there is her green grave, until the world is changed, and all the days of her life are utterly forgotten by men that come after, and elanor and niphredil bloom no more east of the Sea.

In other words Arwen, being heartbroken, **leaves Gondor and goes to live in Lórien for a year or so** before she died, and her grave just happened to be in the place she died in.

Comment: And an important note that the asker has overlooked: *Arwen is not actually **buried**.* She just died there and autumn leaves covered her body, but there was no one there *to* bury her, or knew to find her.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that "the mallorn-leaves were falling, but spring had not yet come" is a sign that the power of the Elves has faded from Middle Earth (previously the old leaves did not fall until the new ones grew). So it is quite appropriate that Arwen dies here in this symbol of the end of the time of the Elves.

Comment: @AAT - good catch, but IIRC the book is unclear if that's a general property of mallorn or if it's due to the influence of Galadriel's ring.

Comment: @Shadur yes I overlooked that important bit of info. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @AAT, that's a very sad and beautiful piece of symbology. Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DarthSatan, I was looking for exactly this!